# I need a specific regex pattern for Java and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I need a regular expression with following conditions:

- min 5 characters, no max characters (only letters and numbers)
- must contain minimum 4 letters
- must contain minimum 1 number

E.g. of correct results:
root1
1root
ro1ot
Roo11t
etc...

Currently I have the pattern `^(?=.*\d{1,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{4,}).{5,}$`

But this seems to also accept special characters...?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: min 5 chars, but is it restricted to numbers and letters?

Comment: Yes, I should specify that. Question edited.

Comment: I'm not even sure the criteria can be checked with regex, it's too dynamic.

Comment: `ro1ot` seems not matches `^(?=.*\d{1,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{4,}).{5,}$`

Comment: Accepted Loamhoof's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.{5,}` that's why it allows special characters (dot = everything (except line feeds and such in fact)). Change it to `[a-z0-9]{5,}` or whatever you want.

Note: `(?=.*\d{1,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{4,})` only check the 2th and 3rd requirement, but don't say anything about the wanted nature of the characters.

**Edit:**
Other problem: your specification says "at least 4 letters" but your regex says "4 consecutive letters". Also, use [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) quantifiers.

```
/^(?=.*?\d)(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){4})[a-z0-9]{5,}$/i
```

`(?=.*?\d)` => you don't need to check for more than 1 number, once you found it, stop.
`(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){4})` => changed to find 4 letters, but not consecutive. Also, added an insensitive case modifier `i` at the end (in JS, in Java you're not declaring it the same way).

Comment: @Zwammer seen another problem also (and making some improvement). Editing

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. Regex can be quite a mystery for the inexperienced :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ugly, but this appears to work:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*(([a-zA-Z]{4,}\d)|([a-zA-Z]{3,}\d[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]{2,}\d[a-zA-Z]{2,})|([a-zA-Z]+\d[a-zA-Z]{3,})|(\d[a-zA-Z]{4,}))[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```